# Create a custom federated data set in TensorFlow Federated

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I'd like to adapt the recurrent autoencoder from this [blog post](https://rickyhan.com/jekyll/update/2017/09/14/autoencoders.html) to work in a federated environment.

I've modified the model slightly to conform with the example shown in the [TFF image classification tutorial.](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification#creating_a_model_with_keras)

```
def create_compiled_keras_model():
  model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.LSTM(2, input_shape=(10, 2), name='Encoder'),
      tf.keras.layers.RepeatVector(10, name='Latent'),
      tf.keras.layers.LSTM(2, return_sequences=True, name='Decoder')]
  )

  model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
  return model

model = create_compiled_keras_model()

sample_batch = gen(1)
timesteps, input_dim = 10, 2

def model_fn():
  keras_model = create_compiled_keras_model()
  return tff.learning.from_compiled_keras_model(keras_model, sample_batch)
```

The gen function is defined as follows:

```
import random

def gen(batch_size):
    seq_length = 10

    batch_x = []
    batch_y = []

    for _ in range(batch_size):
        rand = random.random() * 2 * np.pi

        sig1 = np.sin(np.linspace(0.0 * np.pi + rand, 3.0 * np.pi + rand, seq_length * 2))
        sig2 = np.cos(np.linspace(0.0 * np.pi + rand, 3.0 * np.pi + rand, seq_length * 2))

        x1 = sig1[:seq_length]
        y1 = sig1[seq_length:]
        x2 = sig2[:seq_length]
        y2 = sig2[seq_length:]

        x_ = np.array([x1, x2])
        y_ = np.array([y1, y2])
        x_, y_ = x_.T, y_.T

        batch_x.append(x_)
        batch_y.append(y_)

    batch_x = np.array(batch_x)
    batch_y = np.array(batch_y)

    return batch_x, batch_x #batch_y
```

So far I've been unable to find any documentation which does not use sample data from the TFF repository.

How can I modify this to create a federated data set and begin training?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At a very high-level, to use an arbitrary dataset with TFF the following steps are needed:

1. Partition the dataset into *per client* subsets (how to do so is a much larger question)
2. Create a [tf.data.Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.13/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset?hl=en) per client subset
3. Pass a list of all (or a subset) of the Dataset objects to the federated optimization.

### What is happening in the tutorial

The [Federated Learning for Image Classification tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification#creating_a_model_with_keras) uses [tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/build_federated_averaging_process) to build up a federated optimization using the FedAvg algorithm.

In that notebook, the following code is executing one round of federated optimization, where the client datasets are passed to the process' `.next` method:

```
   state, metrics = iterative_process.next(state, federated_train_data)
```

Here `federated_train_data` is a Python `list` of `tf.data.Dataset`, one per client participating in the round.

### The ClientData object

The canned datasets provided by TFF (under [tff.simulation.datasets](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/simulation/datasets)) are implemented using the [tff.simulation.ClientData](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/simulation/ClientData) interface, which manages the client → dataset mapping and `tff.data.Dataset` creation.

If you're planning to re-use a dataset, implementing it as a `tff.simulation.ClientData` may make future use easier.

Answer (score 4):

Accepted answer is well explained. if you guys need a code implementation for the conversion of tensor to clientdata object, you can find in this [github repository](https://github.com/CS-savvy/experiment_with_tf_federated/blob/master/train_tff.py).

where I have used `tff.simulation.FromTensorSlicesClientData` to convert mnist dataset to multiple tff client data.